# All compact complex manifolds with deformations unobstructed

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I want to find out all the compact complex manifolds with deformations unobstructed, that is to say, for a compact complex manifold $X$, the local universal deformation space is smooth and isomorphic to an open set in $H^1(X,T_X)$.

There are 3 main classes which are already well-known:

1.Compact complex manifold $X$ with $H^2(X,T_X)=0$.
2.Calabi-Yau manifold(Compact Kähler manifold with canonical bundle trival)
3.$\partial\bar\partial$-complex symplectic manifold($\partial\bar\partial$-manifold with a nondegenerate $d$-closed $(2,0)$ form)

For the second class, it is proved by Tian and Todorov, and the Kähler condition can be weakened to the condition that the $\partial\bar\partial$-lemma holds(a manifold with $\partial\bar\partial$-lemma holds is called $\partial\bar\partial$-manifold), and the $\partial\bar\partial$ condition can be weakened to Frolicher spectral sequence degenerates at $E_1$ or the homotopy abelianness of the differential graded algebra $(Λ^{0,∗}(T_X), \bar\partial) $.(which one is weaker?)

For the third class, I'm not sure my description is equivalent to the one in [KV19](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.05258v1.pdf), since it's the only source I know which talks about the unobstructed deformations of holomorphically symplectic manifolds. Actually in [KV19], the authors consider the holomorphically symplectic manifolds with Dolbeault cohomology group
$H^{0,2}_{\bar ∂} (X) = H^2(X,\mathcal O_X)$ generated by $∂$-closed $(0, 2)$-forms, and the condition that all $∂$-exact holomorphic 3-forms on $X$ vanish can be deduce by $\partial\bar\partial$-lemma.

My question is: apart from these 3 classes and their slightly generalizations, are there any other  manifolds with deformations unobstructed? 
(By the way, apart from the first class, the $\partial\bar\partial$ condition seems necessary for unobstructed deformations, I wonder whether
there exist manifolds with $H^2(X,T_X)=0$ but the $\partial\bar\partial$-lemma not hold? )

Comment: You also have manifolds with $H^1(X,TX)=0$. As for finding **all**  manifolds with unobstructed deformation space, this sounds like an impossible task.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan, the $H^1(X,T_X)=0$ case is trivial since the local deformation space is a  point, and why it seems impossible to figure out all unobstructed manifolds? where  the main difficulty lies in?

Comment: Tom, whether the case $H^1(X,T_X)=0$ is trivial or not depends on what you mean by "I want to find out all the compact complex manifolds with deformations unobstructed". For example, let's consider the simplest case of complex dimension $2$. Let's restrict ourselves to the simplest topological case, say $b_2(S)=1$.  Can you find out all the compact complex surfaces in this class with unobstructed deformations? If you try, you will recover the list of 50 fake projective planes:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fake_projective_plane which all have $H^1(X,TX)=0$. This list is far from trivial...

Comment: @Dmitri Panov, thanks for the wonderful examples you have provided, but I can't see it is related to this question, since for any $H^1(X,T_X)=0$ case, the deformations are unobstructed, we don't need to figure out all the explicit examples, isn't it?

Comment: @Tom I can modify the example. Let's look for surfaces with $b_2=2$, $b_1=0$. Then 100 fake projective planes give us 100 unobstructed moduli spaces - just blow up a point on a fake plane.  How would you find all such moduli spaces? I.e. what is the number of unobstructed components of moduli spaces of general type with $b_2=2$, $b_1=0$? I guess no one knowns... There are very few surfaces for which the large moduli space is understood, see for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.2583.pdf Question 2.2 . Without making a complete classification of surfaces how would one answer your question?

Comment: @Dmitri Panov, it really make sense, thanks!

Comment: My suggestion is to pick up a class of complex manifolds and study its deformation space. Already this is a very difficult and worthy task.